# How to covert nested struct into nested map for Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to batchwrite into AWS DynamoDB, and I have to reformat the dataFrame before the loading, now my question is how to convert deep structType dataFrame into deep Map format which can be recognized by DynamoDB and needn't define fields by fields manually ?

Environment: Apache Spark 2.4.3/Spark 2.4.3 in Databricks, Scala 2.11, DynamoDB

The source has a deep structure like below

```
root
 |-- PK: string (nullable = false)
 |-- SK: string (nullable = false)
 |-- ee: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- kv: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- ss: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- pp: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- gg: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- nn: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- mm: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ll: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- le: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- lep: struct (nullable = true)
```

I found some samples but normally they can only handle 1-2 level nested structure, but my dataFrame is "deeper" for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my final solution:

```
/** convert from json to map, then wrap with AttributeValue class */
val tempMap = new ObjectMapper().readValue(testStringText, new TypeReference[JMap[String, Object]](){})
val testMap = toAttribute(tempMap)
new AttributeValue().withM(testMap.getM())

/** nest conversion - scala to java class, wrap with AttributeValue */
def toAttribute(m: Any): AttributeValue = {
    m match {
      case sm: java.util.LinkedHashMap[_, _] => {
        new AttributeValue().withM(sm.map(kv => (kv._1.toString, toAttribute(kv._2))).asJava)
      }
      case sl: java.util.ArrayList[_] => {
        new AttributeValue().withL(sl.map(item => toAttribute(item)).asJava.asInstanceOf[JCollection[AttributeValue]])
      }
      case st: String => new AttributeValue().withS(st)
      case bol: Boolean => new AttributeValue().withBOOL(bol)
      case dbl: java.lang.Double => new AttributeValue().withN(dbl.toString)
      case int: java.lang.Integer => new AttributeValue().withS(int.toString)
      case _ => {
        new AttributeValue()
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below function will handle deeply nested dataframe with any level.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

// TODO: Instead of while/for loop, we can use pattern matching also.
def getFlattenDF(dataFrame: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    var df = dataFrame
    var flag = true
    while (flag) {
      for ((name, types) <- df.dtypes) {
        if (types.startsWith("Array"))
          df = df.withColumn(name, explode_outer(col(name)))
        else if(types.startsWith("Map"))
          df = df.selectExpr("*", s"explode_outer($name)").drop(name)
        else if (types.startsWith("Struct"))
          df = df.selectExpr(Array("*") ++ df.select(s"$name.*").columns.map(s => s"$name" + "." + s + s" as $name" + s"_$s"): _*).drop(name)
      }
      flag = false
      for ((name, types) <- df.dtypes) {
        if (types.startsWith("Array") || types.startsWith("Struct") || types.startsWith("Map"))
          flag = true
      }
    }
    df
  }

 val df = //input dataframe

 getFlattenDF(df)
```

Comment: After tried, it came out an error "org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: The number of aliases supplied in the AS clause does not match the number of columns output by the UDTF expected 2 aliases but got <field-xxx>"

Comment: Is it possible to paste single row of your dataframe here?

Comment: Here's the masked row: 
[[,,,,, [s,,,,,], [ww,,,,,], [ac -> [[, a8, fe]], cd -> [[, 12, e]], vv -> [[, f6, f]], Cd -> [[, 12, true]]], [ss,, ee,,, 12,, [,, 12.12, 12.12],,, ee, 2t,,,,,, ss,,,,,,,], [cc,,,,,],,,,,, [ff,, 12,, 12-12, [ss,, ff,,, dd], 12-12,],,,, [ss,, ss,,, 1212,, [,, 12.1212, 12.12],,, uu, tt,,,,,, ww,,,,,,,]]]

Comment: And previous error traces to the code "df = df.withColumn(name, explode_outer(col(name)))"

Comment: For map type column explode was not working if we use that in withColumn. But explode for map type will work if use that in select clause. Updated the post, check if that works.